# DoesFit method for jigsaw puzzle fails after a few pieces are placed

Tags: java, algorithm

I am creating a  jigsaw puzzle solver. For this I need a `doesFit` method to see if the pieces fit but my the method fails after a few pieces are placed. The pieces sides are club, spade, diamond, or heart in/out. I used enums for them and opposites are supposed to add to zero.

```
public boolean doesFit(int row, int col, Piece piece){ 
    if(board.isOccupied(row, col) == true) return false;
    if(board.isOccupied(row, col-1) && piece.getSides()[Cardinal.WEST.getNumVal()].getNumVal() + board.getPiece(row, col-1).getSides()[Cardinal.EAST.getNumVal()].getNumVal() != 0)return false;
    if(board.isOccupied(row, col+1) && piece.getSides()[Cardinal.EAST.getNumVal()].getNumVal() + board.getPiece(row, col+1).getSides()[Cardinal.WEST.getNumVal()].getNumVal() != 0)return false;            
    if(board.isOccupied(row-1, col) && piece.getSides()[Cardinal.NORTH.getNumVal()].getNumVal() + board.getPiece(row-1, col).getSides()[Cardinal.SOUTH.getNumVal()].getNumVal() != 0)return false;
    if(board.isOccupied(row+1, col) && piece.getSides()[Cardinal.SOUTH.getNumVal()].getNumVal() + board.getPiece(row+1, col).getSides()[Cardinal.NORTH.getNumVal()].getNumVal() != 0)return false;
    return true;
}

public boolean isOccupied(int row, int col){
    if(isValid(row, col) == true && board[row][col] != null) return true;
        return false;
}
public boolean isValid(int numRows, int numCols){
    if(numRows < 0 || numCols < 0 || numRows > board.length - 1 || numCols > board[0].length - 1)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
```

Comment: I can only guess as I can see that this method does not take into consideration the edges of the puzzle. How would your `board.isOccupied()` method behave if the values of `row-1` or `col-1` are either `<0` or `row+1>height` or `col+1>width`?

Comment: We are going to need to see more of your code, a markup (indent) fix would also help. Looking at this for 10 minutes and still don't see the problem, mostly due to the lack of information

Comment: Sorry about the code formatting. I also added isOccupied() and isValid().